# Why isn't my chrome extension working?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've spent hours and hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my chrome extension. I know that my function.js code is good because it works with an html page that I link it to, but perhaps it isn't right for chrome extensions?
All help is appreciated

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Font Find",
      "description": "This extension allows you to click on any text, and find out what font it is written in.",
      "version": "1.0",
      "background": {
              "page": "popup.html",
              "persistent": true
          },

    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
      ],

      "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Find the Font",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"//,
    //    "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },

          "background": { "scripts": ["jquery.min.js"] },


        "content_scripts": [
            {
                "matches": [
                    "http://*/*",
                    "https://*/*"
                ],
                "js": [
                   "function.js"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**`popup.html` file** (note it isn't set as the popup)

```
                            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css"/> -->

                    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
                    <script src="function.js"></script> 

                </head>

            </html>
```

**`function.js` file**

```
             "use strict";

             $("body").append('Test');

            document.body.ondblclick = function(event){

                //event.stopPropagation();
                var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

                alert( "What you clicked on:" + $(target).text() + "   It's font-family is: " + $(target).attr("font-family") );

            }
```

**`function.js` file**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "function.js"
    });
});
```

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because it is a "Why isn't this code working?" question. Please be more specific. For example, do you have any errors? How is it "not working"? Did you install it correctly?

Comment: Sorry if i'm not adhering to all the rules of stack, I'm quite new to question asking. I'm not receiving errors. I did install it correctly. When I click on my icon, I should be able to double click on any piece of text and an alert box will pop up telling me its font-family.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm guessing that there might be a problem with the installation. Did you correctly add this to Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I did correctly add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, edit the `manifest.json` file. Add this code:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ], "js": [
        "jquery.min.js",
        "function.js"
    ], "run_at": "document_start"
}]
```

And now, use this code in `function.js` file.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.body.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        alert("What you clicked on: " + $(target).text() + "   It's font-family is: " + $(target).attr("font-family"));
    }, true);
});
```

I tested this code and it works. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I really appreciate it. I'm working on my javascript! It's getting better, I hope.

Comment: Why didn't my original JS work for the chrome extension?

Comment: @Steven, probably your jquery.min.js is not injected at the time document starts, before your jquery.js is loaded, other place where use jquery is called.